# How to use the latest version of Vaadin4Spring EventBus framework with Maven?

Tags: maven, vaadin, vaadin4spring

I have a Spring Boot project with Vaadin, I would like to integrate the Vaadin4Spring EventBus framework:

https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/tree/master/spring-vaadin-eventbus

The author says:

> Please note, that the Event Bus API changed in version 0.0.5

However, if I add the Maven dependency inside my pom.xml:

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-vaadin-eventbus</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

Maven downloads the `0.0.4.RELEASE` version. I have tried to explicitly set the following versions:

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-vaadin-eventbus</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    ...

    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-vaadin-eventbus</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    ...

    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-vaadin-eventbus</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

I also tried to set the entire `Spring4Vaadin` addon as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-vaadin</artifactId>
  <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
...


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-vaadin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.5</version>
</dependency>
...

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-vaadin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>    
...

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-vaadin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But neither of them worked.

Basically, I cannot do this:

```
 @Autowired
 EventBus.ApplicationEventBUs appEventBus;

 @Autowired
 EventBus.UIEventBus UIEventBus;
 ...
```

Because, as said in the README.md on GitHub:

> Please note, that the Event Bus API changed in version 0.0.5. From now
>   on, you have to declare which event bus to inject by using a specific
>   interface (previously, everything was EventBus and you used an
>   annotation to specify which bus to get). The reasons for this change
>   were

So in the version `0.0.4.RELEASE` (which Maven sees as LATEST), the inner interfaces `ApplicationEventBus` and `UIEventBus` are not defined.

So, how can I use the true latest version of the addon?

Comment: The [version 0.0.4.RELEASE](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|spring-vaadin-eventbus) is the newest on Maven Central.

Comment: @khmarbaise How can I use the inner interfaces then? Download the sources and compile?

Comment: It looks like this is the only possibility cause the maintainers haven't published yet a new version on Central...may be giving a issue hint in the project might speed up the process..

Comment: Yeah, I did like you are saying, now version `0.0.5-SNAPSHOT` is the one to go with.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the answer I put in the vaadin forums, over here as well:

Vaadin addons has a nice Event Bus implementation. Check https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/tree/master/samples/eventbus-sample

I have done this using a spring enabled (NOT spring boot) Vaadin application, but it might work without Spring as well I guess, Short steps:
1. Add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.spring.addons</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-spring-addon-eventbus</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Import EventBusConfiguration.class into your Spring configuration (may not be required if Spring Boot is used with @EnableAutoConfiguration)
3. Wire in appropriate event bus (check doumentations for different types available), here I am using one that works per UI instance:

   ```
   @Autowired
   private EventBus.UIEventBus uiEventBus;
   ```
4. Publish event as required, eg:

   ```
   uiEventBus.publish(this, new RefreshMainViewEvent(this, "Usage details updated"));
   ```
5. Subscribe to event in the other component class

   ```
   @PostConstruct
   public void afterPropertiesSet() {

       uiEventBus.subscribe(this, false);
   }
   ```
6. Add the action to be done on event (in the same class here) :

   ```
   @EventBusListenerMethod
   public void closeSymmUsageWindow(RefreshMainViewEvent event) {
       logger.debug("Received {}", event);
       //blah
   }
   ```